# How to pass char* by value C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, reference, char

I have defined an attribute of type `char* content` that accepts a string that contains even `\0` like characters, in this way I could not use the `string` type.

The problem here when I tried to define the setter for content is this :

```
void MyClass::setContent(char* content)
{
    if(this->contentLength!=0){
        if(this->content)
            free(this->content);
        this->content = (char*)malloc(this->contentLength);
        memset(this->content,0,this->contentLength);
        memcpy(this->content,content,this->contentLength);
    }
}
```

knowing that `contentLength` is also an attribute of `MyClass`.

However in another stack, i have defined a function that returns object of `MyClass` as this :

```
MyClass myfunction(args) {
    MyClass myclass;
    /**
     *Do some stuff on myclass
     */
    return myclass;
}
```

on the other stack, i have defined this :

```
MyClass element = myFunction(args);
```

And here I have lost the content because it's always pointing to the address of `myclass` in the first stack.

how can I copy the `content` to the new object `element`?

I am working on `C++98`, and any solution on `c++11` could not be implemented.

Comment: If you have a C++98 compiler, you could compile (from its source code) a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in start of 2021, and then you have a C++14 compiler on your computer (and of course you can use [`std::string` and the string library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I have no choice but to use C++98. I am working in an embedded environment.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, the problem is that `content` is containing characters and symbols  that to my knowledge are not accepted if I use a string like `\0`.

Comment: The `std::string` accepts any `char`, including `'\0'`.  C++98 or modern C++.  But if not `std::string`, another viable alternative better than a raw `char*` is `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have defined an attribute of type `char*` content that accepts a string that contains even `\0` like characters,

There's your problem right there.   If you're passing a `char *` around - and even worse, using it to manage dynamically allocated memory returned by `malloc()`, there are many things that can go wrong.

Simply pass around a `std::vector<char>` instead.   It keeps track of its own length, doesn't care how many values of `'\0'` it contains, and can be dynamically resized as needed.    For example, you could then reimplement

```
void MyClass::setContent(const std::vector<char> &content)
{
    this->content = content;    // this will copy all of the characters
                                //  from content to this-content
                                //  and manage memory for you
}
```

There is plenty of documentation on `std::vector` available for example [cppreference vector page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that explains what operations a `vector` supports.   As long as you take the trouble to use its operations appropriately (it's not a free-for-all) a `std::vector<char>` will make your life easier.    While there have been some evolutions of `std::vector` between C++ standards, even the C++98 version should be adequate for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor
When you return an object by value, a copy constructor is invoked to copy your object.

If you do not create one manually, a default copy constructor is generated. It just copies the pointer, so two pointers refer to the same array.

You may create a copy constructor manually like this:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& other)
{
    this->contentLength = other.contentLength;
    this->content = (char*) malloc(this->contentLength);
    memcpy(this->content, other.content, this->contentLength);

    // Copy every other field manually here, if you have any.
}
```

**Update:**
See answers by eerorika and Peter for better practices and how to avoid this need instead.

Answer (score 2):

> How to pass char* by value C++?

Same way as other types are passed by value: Don't use a reference parameter. Example:

```
void function_name(char*); // the pointer will be passed by value
```

> how can I copy the `content` to the new object element?

That's what you did. You copied the pointer and thus the copy points to the same array.

If you wish to make a deep copy, then you could allocate a new array, point the new pointer to this separate allocation, and copy the string from the old array.

But that's not necessarily how you *should* write the class. What you should do instead is to use `std::string` member or `std::vector<char>` depending on use case.

---

> a string that contains even \0 like characters, in this way I could not use the `string` type.

It is unclear what you mean by this. If you attempt to say that `std::string` cannot hold null terminator characters, then you are mistaken.

---

P.S. Avoid using `malloc` in C++.